# Table/TD border will not show on echo td

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table

I'm echoing a table from mySql. The TD border is not showing up no matter how I input the code. The thead border is showing up just fine.

This is what I have.

```js
// Loop to show results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td style=text-align:center>".$row['ETF'].
  "</td>";
  echo "<td style=text-align:center>".$row['ETF NAME'].
  "</td>";
  echo "<td style=text-align:center>".$row['1 YR Direction %'].
  "</td>";
  echo "<td style=text-align:center>".$row['Holding Name'].
  "</td>";
  echo "<td style=text-align:center>".$row['Industry'].
  "</td>";
  echo "<td style=text-align:center>".$row['Percent Holdings'].
  "</td>";

  "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

```css
  <style type="text/css">thead,
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #992c29;
  color: #f7f4f4;
  border: 2px solid black;
  tr,
  td {
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not closed your `th` selector, so the styles directly below it are considering invalid syntax, and will never execute.

Closing your `th` selector by adding in the missing curly brace (`}`) will resolve your issue:

```
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #992c29;
  color: #f7f4f4;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

In addition to this, ensure that no other selectors are overriding your styles with higher **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, i just updated it and it still wont work. I also think that there is something that is overriding this style but i can't find it. Im using wordpress, would this be an issue with the style sheet? I updated the stylesheet aswell though.

Comment: Have you tried an !important tag to see if that will overrides the style? Also have you looked tin the developer tools to see where the styles are coming from?

Comment: You can use the [**F12 Developer Tools**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699337(v=vs.85).aspx) to check which styles are overriding your own. Your selectors are indeed valid, so it's quite possible that the styles are being overridden. While `!important` would *probably* solve that issue, I would recommend against its use, as it's a 'last resort'. It's also possible that caching is an issue. Try pressing `CTRL + F5` to refresh your style sheet reference, and then forcibly clear your CSS cache by holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i'm defiantly going to take some tips off you for when i'm explaining things. Great explanations, Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

Close off missing

```
thead,
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #992c29;
  color: #f7f4f4;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
tr,
td {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```